# Is there ever a reason to call join when using pool.map while using python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

As `multiprocessing.Pool().map()` blocks the main process from moving ahead with the execution. And, yet it gets stated everywhere that `join` should be called after `close` as a good practice. I wanted to understand, through example, what could ever be the scenario under which using `join` makes sense after a `multiprocessing.Pool().map()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does it state that "good practice"? If you have no further need of the pool, i.e. you do not plan on submitting any more tasks *and* your program is not terminating but you want to release the resource used by the pool and "clean up" right away, you can just call *terminate* either explicitly or implicitly, which happens if you use a `with` block as follows:

```py
with Pool() as pool:
   ...
# terminate is called implicitly when the above block exits
```

But note that `terminate` will *not* wait for outstanding tasks, if any, to complete. If there are submitted tasks that queued up to run but not yet running or are currently running, they will be canceled.

Calling `close` prevents further tasks from being submitted and should only be called when you have no further use for the pool. Calling `join`, which requires that you first call `close`, will wait for any outstanding tasks to complete and the processes in the pool to terminate. But if you are using `map`, by definition that blocks until the tasks submitted complete. So unless you have any *other* tasks you submitted there is no compelling need to call `close` followed by `join`. These calls are, however, useful to wait for outstanding tasks submitted with, for example, `apply_async` to complete without having to explicitly call `get` on the `AsyncResult` instance returned by that call:

```py
pool = Pool()
pool.submit(worker1, args=(arg1, arg2))
pool.submit(worker2, args=(arg3,))
pool.submit(worker3)
# wait for all 3 tasks to complete
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Of course, the above is only useful if you do not need any return values from the worker functions.

**So to answer your question: Not really; only if you happen to have *other* tasks submitted asynchronously whose completion you are awaiting. It is, however, one way of immediately releasing pool resource if you are not planning on exiting your program right away, the other way being to call method `terminate`.**

Comment: I confused ```imap_ordered``` with ```map```. In fact map with all other parallel mappers. You are right all those resources I read are for other mappers. My bad. However, your answer is a great learning and so I'll leave the question be for anyone who might stumble

Comment: Of course, if you are using `imap_unordered`, which returns an *iterator*, then you either have to iterate that *iterator* to get return values to ensure that your submitted tasks have started and completed.

Comment: If you do not fully iterate the *iterator*, then depending on the *chunksize* there is no guarantee that all of the tasks represented by the items of the *iterator* will get submitted. This is a "lazy" form of submission.

Comment: Although using `close` followed by `join` does seem to ensure that of the items of the *iterator* are submitted and completed even if you do not iterate it.